# htaccess 301 redirect http to https doesn't work

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I updated from http to https today.
So far, so good. Everything is working, but the redirect command.
When I click on external social media or websites that link to my blog still using the old version http, it's not being redirected.

This is how part of my file looks:

```
# -FrontPage-
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName zoomingjapan.com
AuthUserFile /home/zoomingj/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/zoomingj/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^zoomingjapan.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.zoomingjapan.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://zoomingjapan.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I also tried this instead, no positive result:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !FeedBurner    [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !FeedValidator [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This is an [http link](http://zoomingjapan.com/cuisine/matcha/). You can test and see for yourself that it's not being redirected.

Could a caching plugin be interfering? I'm using LiteSpeed Cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've put the redirect code in the wrong place. It needs to go *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section. By placing the redirect code *after* the WordPress front-controller it will never be processed unless the request is for a physical file.

However, your first attempt is not correct (it's missing the check for HTTPS), so would result in a redirect loop (if it was executed).

A standard HTTP to HTTPS would take the following form:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, ideally you should also combine this with a canonical www/non-www redirect as well, to avoid duplicate content or multiple redirects. For example, if the preference is for www (and you have no other subdomains), then something like the following:

```
# Redirect bare domain to www and HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**UPDATE:** If your preference is for the non-www version, then you can change the first rule to read something like:

```
# Redirect www to non-www (and HTTPS)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(Assuming you've also changed the necessary settings in WordPress as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```